# The snapshot return null for me, how to solve the problem?

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I get null from this data

```
private fun getUserName() {

        databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://tailoring-e7e0c-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/").getReference("Users")
        databaseReference.child(uAuth.currentUser?.uid.toString()).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                var userList :User
                userList = snapshot.getValue(User::class.java)!!
                userName=userList?.cid.toString()
                Toast.makeText(this@ProductDetail,"Username detected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })

    }
```

and this is the screen shot of the firebase realtime database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF4ec.jpg)

Comment: How do you check that? Where is the snapshot object null?

Comment: @AlexMamo the userList part I checked. it shows null

Comment: I cannot see any userList part logged.

Comment: @AlexMamo ` java.lang.NullPointerException at com.final_tailoring_online.orderSystem.productSystem.ProductDetail$getTailorName$1.onDataChange(ProductDetail.kt:150)` this is the error message view for it

Comment: What exactly exists at line 150? Please provide more info so we can help.